# PHP/Apache Nice URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to create nice URLs for the website.

I have this file structure:

```
public:
  user:
    user.php
  index.php
```

I want to make it so that someone can enter the url:

```
http://www.example.com/user/{user name here}
```

and the request will be sent to:

```
user.php?name={user name here}
```

but I don't want them to see the file.

I think I may have to do this with .htacces but I'm not sure how.

I'm sorry if my question layout is not very good.

Comment: see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this rule in `/user/.htaccess`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /user/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /user\.php\?name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ user.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks :)

I'll accept it when I'm allowed